# UITabBarController transition not working when set from storyboard

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller, transition

My app has four tabs in the UITabBarController. I am using the storyboard to layout my app. In `Attributes Inspector` I set the `Transition Style` of the UITabBarController to `Cross Dissolve`. But when I run the app, the tabs still snap into place without any transition. Thanks for any help.

*UPDATE*

Further investigation has taken me to the delegate method

```
`tabBarController:animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:toViewController:`
```

but the problem with this method is that the documentation says the method is `Called to allow the delegate to return a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning delegate object for use during a noninteractive tab bar view controller transition.` Here I take non-interactive to mean "Not due to user tappings". But the transitions I seek to define are precisely for when the user taps on a TabBar icon.

Comment: If only I could down vote the person who down voted this question for not giving an explanation.

Comment: When people down vote without giving explanations why I don't waste my time asking for an explanation. But @KonsolLabapen thanks for the reply; it has so much more.

Comment: There is a great talk on this from WWDC 2013 : 218.

In particular, interactive transitions are ones where the pace and success of the animation is dependent on something the user is doing during the animation ( e.g. swipe between tab views.)

Apologies for resurrecting an old answer, but I would have liked to see this reference when I hit this question.

Answer (score 1):

The following article should have what you need. It has all sorts of examples and has a git project as well. http://objectivetoast.com/2014/03/17/custom-transitions-on-ios/. The git projects to look at are

https://github.com/ObjectiveToast/CustomTransitions

https://github.com/twotoasters/Toast